# Laravel Pulse: How to add non-application servers?

Tags: laravel, pulse

The recently-released still-beta Laravel Pulse application has on its website a screenshot of the server stats module:

[image: server stats]

The [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/pulse) mentions a php artisan command (`php artisan pulse:check`) to be run in order to feed data to this report. However, it seems that this would require installing PHP and at least a clean Laravel install on each monitored server, even for example a database or cache server that is generally only given its essentials like MySql and Redis.

Is there no other way to send this server health data back to Pulse?